# How can I tell when a Azure AD client secret expires?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have many applications registered in Azure AD Tenant and many of these are having client secret keys issued for 1 or 2 years. Is there a way to get an alert before the expiry as expired keys will cause an outage.

Answer (score 5):

We can also query the `application` to get the end-date of secret key. Here is a code sample using **client credentials flow** via the Azure Graph client for your reference. And please ensure that you have grant the app with `Directory.Read.All` permission to this API for using client credentials flow.

```cs
var graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
var appId= "";
var appObjectId = "";
var secret = "";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId,secret);
var tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientCredential).Result.AccessToken;

Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

var app = activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(appObjectId).ExecuteAsync().Result;

foreach (var passwordCredential in app.PasswordCredentials)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"KeyID:{passwordCredential.KeyId}\r\nEndDate:{passwordCredential.EndDate}\r\n");
}
```

Comment: `activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(appObjectId).ExecuteAsync().Result` should really be `await activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(appObjectId).ExecuteAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

At this time, **there is no out of the box mechanism for alerting when client secrets are expiring**.

You can vote for this ask in the Azure AD Feedback Entry: [Need email alert option when keys are about to expire](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9392007-need-email-alert-option-when-keys-are-about-to-exp)

Alternatively, **you can build your own alerting mechanism by polling the Graph** (currently the Azure AD Graph and eventually the Microsoft Graph once /servicePrincipals is in /v1.0/ in there).

Query [`/servicePrincipals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity) and filter on `PasswordCredentials.EndDate` and `KeyCredentials.EndDate`.

You'll need to do your filtering client side since Graph doesn't support filtering on these values yet.

## 2021-12-07 Update

Azure AD Graph has been deprecated.

**Query Microsoft Graph's [`/servicePrincipals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and filter on the `EndDate` property of the [`PasswordCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) object.**

Comment: Thanks, Do you have sample code? Also, Can this be done through a headless process in App Auth flow?

Comment: The link's broken

Comment: @Daniel - updated answer and link for Microsoft Graph versus the now-deprecated Azure AD Graph.

Answer (score 1):

I created a "simple" one-line Azure Powershell command to show all principals that have or will expire in the next 30 days. Using that as a data feed for an email (like Send-MailMessage) or other alerting tool may be fairly straight forward.

```
Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true | Select-Object AppId, displayName -ExpandProperty PasswordCredentials | Where-Object EndDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(30) | Sort-Object EndDate | Format-Table AppId, DisplayName, EndDate
```

Note: If you have multiple secrets on a principal, each one shows up as its own line in the output. If you want to see all your principals and their secret expirations, just remove the Where-Object clause in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logic App to automate the process. I found this useful:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/use-azure-logic-apps-to-notify-of-pending-aad-application-client/ba-p/3014603?fbclid=IwAR3ECopMRsitagEStKLC_yvAmFX4a1Ispn_a8ZFitapPquq9OZcZvQgKVOQ

Comment: What did you find helpful there?