# Get SharePoint App details using Graph REST API

Tags: sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api, provider-hosted

I have an Provider Hosted SharePoint app registered using appreg.aspx. I want to get details of that app like app name, client secret start and end date using Azure Function, so that I can send alert before the app client secret expires. I have already increased the date to 3 years using the PowerShell script.

I went through the question, [Alert on Client Secret Key Expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075464/alert-on-client-secret-key-expiry). But it seems the solution is older. I have used PowerShell script to get app details but I want to use Azure Function as I already have few other functions so maintaining them will be easier.

Is there a way to get app details using Graph REST API?

Thank you!

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but since I have less than 15 reputation points, this is not recorded publicly. Thank you, it worked for me!

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to accept the answer. It's not upvote:)

Comment: Oops I didn't know that. I accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '{app id of your app registered in SharePoint}'` to get the the app details.

You can find client secret endDateTime in the response (the app name is also included):

```
        "passwordCredentials": [
            {
                "customKeyIdentifier": null,
                "endDateTime": "2021-01-16T01:56:20.4750596Z",
                "keyId": "653b5550-23c0-4bff-9fab-f34e91d23dc6",
                "startDateTime": "2020-01-16T01:56:20.4750596Z",
                "secretText": null,
                "hint": null,
                "displayName": null
            }
```

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). And you can have a qucik test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Thank you! I tried with app permission Directory.ReadWrite.All and it worked for me.

Comment: @SushrutParanjape Glad to hear that. You can accept my solution as answer. Thank you!